# Image Tag Not Working In ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, image

I am trying to use normal `<img/>` tag in my .aspx file. The source picture is located in the same directory as the source code. Yet, I am not able to view the image while I debug.

Here is my code:

```
<img alt="Search Icon" src="select.png" style="z-index: 113; left: 230px; position: absolute; top: 143px" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following 5 option you can try and check

1) Remove `z-index` and check

2) put `~/` before name in src

3) `src='<%= Url.Content("select.png") %>'`

4) use `asp:image` control instead

5) add runat="server"

Answer (score 0):

Look into the source of the generated file (in the browser) and check if the URL to the image is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `select.png` image is in the same directory that contains the `.aspx` file

Answer (score 0):

Check you solution where your image is located. Try to Add Content in Image folder in your project and paste there all of your image files.
Try to use Image control .
Do Something like this:

```
    <asp:Image ImageUrl="Content/images/select.png" tooltip="Search Icon" height="55px" width="60px" alt="" ID="Image1" runat="server" /></p>
```

Regards

Comment: when i browser using ImageUrl the browser window can only  detect .aspx and .cs file only... huhu

Comment: try to insert other image file in your project...and test it if its working or not.